# How to use BERT just for ENTITY extraction from a Sequence without classification in the NER task?

Tags: nlp, pytorch, named-entity-recognition, named-entity-extraction, bert-language-model

My requirement here is given a sentence(sequence), I would like to just extract the entities present in the sequence without classifying them to a type in the NER task. I see that BertForTokenClassification for NER does the classification. Can this be adapted for just the extraction?

Can BERT just be used to do **entity extraction/identification**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless BERT, NER tagging is usually done by tagging with the IOB format (inside, outside, beginning) or something similar (often the end is also explicitly tagged). The *inside* and *beggining* tags contain the entity type. Something like this:

```
Alex B-PER
is O
going O
to O
Los B-LOC
Angeles I-LOC
```

If you modify your training data, such that there will be only one entity type, the model will only learn to detect the entities without knowing what type the entity is.

```
Alex B
is O
going O
to O
Los B
Angeles I
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will try that. :)